# How Finalize() get called?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to find if any existing posts in regard to my question and I couldn't find any.

Firstly, my .net book said :
**The supreme base class of .NET, System.Object, defines a virtual method
named Finalize() as**:

```
public class Object
{
 ...
 protected virtual void Finalize() {}
}
```

but I couldn't find this method in the VS definition or https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs

Secondly, since Finalize() is protected, which means you can't really use dot operator to call this method as `thisObject.Finalize()`, same is for Garage Collector, it can't use dot operator to call that method, but we know GC has to call an object's Finalize method before removing the object from memory. so does it mean that there is another public API inside the object class, which can call Finalize() indirectly as:

```
public class Object
{
 ...
 protected virtual void Finalize() {}
 public void XXX()
 {
     Finalize();
 }
}
```

so that the GC can call the method as: object.XXX()?

sorry if you feel my questions are dumb, my foundation of C# knowledge is not very strong

Comment: It will be called when terminate main method.

Comment: It is special in C#, it has dedicated syntax for the finalizer.  The finalizer for someclass is written as ~someclass().  Which takes [you here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,558e5999d9a30d94).  Just a basic way to stop you from defining or calling it yourself by accident.

Comment: _" same is for Garage Collector, it can't use dot operator to call that method"_ - Remember the CLR doesn't have the same limitations that C# does. Member names might be invalid in C#, but not in the CLR. It's worth paying attention to the fact that some functionality is actually provided by the CLR, not by the framework (i.e. not C# code), so the rules are different. And also remember that your code is compiled to Intermediate Language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, If you are using or implementing a *Finalizers* you are more than likely doing something wrong (with very few exceptions, actual any I can think of).

Unlike *constructors* that are called explicitly using the `new` operator, *finalizers* cannot be called *explicitly* from within the code.

**The *garbage collector* is responsible for calling a *finalizer* on an object instance**. Just because you can't call it means little, .Net Framework can do things you can't do.

So in short a developer cannot determine at compile time exactly when the *finalizer* will execute. All we know is that the *finalizer* may run sometime between when an object was last used and when the application shuts down normally (and even then it might not run).